# How do I get X11 XA_WM_CLASS for XA_PRIMARY owner?

Tags: c, linux, window, x11

I want to get the class title of a window which owns the primary clipboard in X Window system.

I have the following code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
Atom real;
unsigned char *data;
int format;
ulong n, extra;


  Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);




  // Get the selection window
 Window window = XGetSelectionOwner(dpy, XA_PRIMARY);
printf("%d\n", (unsigned)window);


 XGetWindowProperty(dpy,  window, XA_WM_NAME, 0, ~0, False,
                        AnyPropertyType, &real, &format, &n, &extra,
                        &data) ;

 //     char *wm_class2 = data + strlen(data) + 1;
  printf("%s\n", data);
 // printf("%s\n", wm_class2);
return 0;
}
```

While it works for `XA_WM_NAME`, it fails for `XA_WM_CLASS`.
Would you please tell me what's wrong with it?

EDIT:
`xprop` doesn't list `WM_CLASS` property by window id.

```
xprop -id  94372511
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Chromium clipboard"
```

Comment: Two comments: 1. There is no XA_WM_TITLE (Do you mean XA_WM_NAME ?). Also note that X clients based on XDG will use NET_WM_NAME atom. Yu might have to query both to cover.

Comment: Also note that XGetWindowProperty will return Success, even if no property is found. You will want to skip the result if XGetWindowProperty fail OR the data is null. Current code check for AND condition.

Comment: @dash-o Thank you for responding. It's my confusion, I'm sorry. I updated it.

Comment: @dash-o But if I replace `XA_WM_CLASS`with `XA_WM_NAME` it prints the window name.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Can you validate that your window (based on ID) has the X properties (WM_CLASS) you are looking for ? Use xprop -id <NUMBER>. This will give you an indication of the primary holder window. It is possible that the owner is a sub-window, and does not have a class. Usually, only top level application will set the WM_CLASS.

Comment: I noticed that window id of the `XGetSelectionOwner` doesn't match to the xprop window id.

Comment: You might want to try to walk the window tree (xwininfo -tree), to find out what is the relationship. It is possible that the selection owner window will not have a class.

Comment: `xprop` doesn't list `WM_CLASS` property by window id.